# how to get servlet variable from xmlhttpresponse

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I am trying to call servlet from html through script, for get the user data(say receipt number) , in servlet, it connects to db and get the document no and document date. when i view the reponsetext, i am getting undefined value. Please help me on how to get response text in proper way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function showCustomer(num) {
 
 var kkk = document.getElementById("num").value;
 alert("this is mango1 "+kkk);
  
 var xmlhttp;
  
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {          
           document.getElementById("pono").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           alert(demo);         
        }
    };
  
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "callserv1?num="+kkk, true); 
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action=""> 
Receipt no <input type="text" name="num" id="num"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showCustomer(num)" value ="call"/>
<p id="demo">Customer info will be listed here...
PO no <input type="text" name="pono" id="pono"/>
Po date <input type="text" name="podt" id="podt"/></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class callserv1 extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
 {
  response.setContentType("text/html");  
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  
  String grnxx =  request.getParameter("num");
  String pono = null;
  String podt = null;
  System.out.println("I am in Servlet");
  System.out.println("input receipt number received: " +grnxx);
  
  try
  {      
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("db connection');
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
  System.out.println("Connection estabilished"+con);
 
  //Input query to get PO and Itemlist for given GRn
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("!!!!DB query!!!");
  
  while(rs.next()) {
   pono = rs.getString("doc");
   podt = rs.getString("dt"); 
   System.out.println("Pono:----   "+pono);
   System.out.println("Podt:----   "+podt);
  }
  
  con.close(); 
  System.out.println("DB Connection closed successfully");
  
  request.setAttribute("pono", pono);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").include(request,response);
  

  
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Connection error: "+e);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to write your output to `out` variable (which you got from `response` object), setting attribute won't work for here.

Comment: could  you please little specific

Comment: Since you are doing an xmlhttp call, you need to send your output using `response` object. So in your case, you should do `out.println(pono);` and your should get as response to your `xmlhttp`.

Comment: okie. I have tried. nbut i am getting [Object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: You have explore that object and if it contains your expected result and then extract it in javascript and do whatever you need to do with it.